# Does a particle need a magnetic field to be affected by a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I understand that anything with a magnetic field also has an electric field and also that a magnetic field is just a messed up electric field, but if you hypothetically had an electron with only a magnetic field, would it attract a proton with only an electric field?

Sorry if this question seems oddly specific and pointless but I think it will help me understand electromagnetism.

Comment: A stationary wire carrying current emits a magnetic field, but no electric field.

Comment: A particle must have electric charge and must be in motion in order for magnetic field to act upon it.

Comment: There are frames of reference where only magnetic field is present. Also, there are frames of reference where only electric field is present. A pure electric field can be seen as a combination of electric and magnetic fields from other frames,  but it can never be seen as a pure magnetic field.

Comment: From a particle physics point of view, electrons and protons always interact via the electromagnetic interaction by exchanging virtual photons.

Answer (score 0):

A charged particle always produces an electric field. If the particle is moving it also produces a magnetic field. Thus, electric and magnetic fields have to be studied as one thing in the electromagnetism framework.

From a quantum point of view, particles are always in motion (due to the uncertainty principle). So electrons and protons will always interact through the electromagnetic force (as any charged particles will do).